# Using AJAX response to fill JSON object

Tags: javascript

I'm using fullcalender.io which takes in a json array of objects. I'm using AJAX to call a php function, which succesfully returns a JSON object which i can see in the console. I just can't get it to full up the `events` object as it tells me events is not defined. I've tried initiating `var events` before but it doesnt the variable isnt defined.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: [
    //Here needs to be filled
  ],
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

    var data = {
      action: 'getCountOfReservationOnDate',
      date: date.format() + " 00:00:00"
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/modules/ajax/ajax_handler.php",
      data: data
    })
    .done((result)=>{
      if(result) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(JSON.parse(result));
        events.push(result); //From here
      } else {
        alert("Failed.")
        console.log(result);
      }
    })
    .fail(function($xhr) {
      var data = $xhr.responseJSON;
      //$("#validationError").text(data.message);
      console.log(data.message);
    })
    .always(()=>{
      //$('#loader').hide();
    })
  }
```

Comment: Have you look up this link? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Comment: I did not! @Amacado This should be a big help thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fullcalender.io provide [some documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) related to ajax usage (events as a json feed). Consider the following script:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: '/modules/ajax/ajax_handler.php'
});
```

You might need to change your `/modules/ajax/ajax_handler.php` to provide the correct output. Since you did not post the code from it I'm not able to check it, but you probably find the answer on the linked document.

Answer (score 0):

Your can try creating a variable where your ajax function can access it,
or create that variable globally at the topmost line in your file

```js
tempEvent
```

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: [
    //Your can for loop the tempEvent to fill here
  ],
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

    var tempEvent = []

    var data = {
      action: 'getCountOfReservationOnDate',
      date: date.format() + " 00:00:00"
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/modules/ajax/ajax_handler.php",
      data: data
    })
    .done((result)=>{
      if(result) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(JSON.parse(result));
        tempEvent.push(result); //From here
      } else {
        alert("Failed.")
        console.log(result);
      }
    })
    .fail(function($xhr) {
      var data = $xhr.responseJSON;
      //$("#validationError").text(data.message);
      console.log(data.message);
    })
    .always(()=>{
      //$('#loader').hide();
    })
  }
```